# Rails form_for layout links in line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, form-for

I have the layout presently using nested_form_for as:

[image]

with the code as simply:

```
    <%= f.label :monday %>           
    <%= f.check_box :monday %>       

    <%= f.label :tuesday %>
    <%= f.check_box :tuesday %>

    <%= f.label :wednesday %>
    <%= f.check_box :wednesday %>

    <%= f.label :thursday %>
    <%= f.check_box :thursday %>
```

But I would like if these attributes could like listed in a straight line with breaks such as:

Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday ....

Is there a setting in nested_form_for to allow this?

**Note below is the HTML generated from the first response**

```
<hr> 
<strong>Day(s) special Will Appear</strong>

<ul id="dayForm">
<label for="campaign_monday">Monday</label>           
<input name="campaign[monday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_monday" name="campaign[monday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />       

<label for="campaign_tuesday">Tuesday</label>
<input name="campaign[tuesday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_tuesday" name="campaign[tuesday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label for="campaign_wednesday">Wednesday</label>
<input name="campaign[wednesday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_wednesday" name="campaign[wednesday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label for="campaign_thursday">Thursday</label>
<input name="campaign[thursday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_thursday" name="campaign[thursday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label for="campaign_friday">Friday</label>
<input name="campaign[friday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_friday" name="campaign[friday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label for="campaign_saturday">Saturday</label>
<input name="campaign[saturday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_saturday" name="campaign[saturday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label for="campaign_sunday">Sunday</label>
<input name="campaign[sunday]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="campaign_sunday" name="campaign[sunday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails form_for helpers help you generate HTML; the HTML generated is still subject to the same rules as other HTML elements.  Rails offers ways to add HTML/CSS to the form fields themselves, which may be what you are looking for.  For example,

```
<%= f.label :monday, :class => 'inline' %>
```

The `:class => 'inline'` adds the class 'inline' to the HTML form element on the page and you can add styling thereafter to `.inline {}` in your css file.

But you could also simply do something like:

Wrap the form fields with a `<ul>` tag,

```
<ul id="dayForm">
  <%= f.label :monday %>           
  <%= f.check_box :monday %>       

  <%= f.label :tuesday %>
  <%= f.check_box :tuesday %>

  <%= f.label :wednesday %>
  <%= f.check_box :wednesday %>

  <%= f.label :thursday %>
  <%= f.check_box :thursday %>
</ul>
```

And in your css file,

```
ul#dayForm {
  list-style: none;
}    

ul#dayForm input {
  display: list-item;
  float: left;
  width: 100px; /* adjust depending on desired size */
}

ul#dayForm label {
  display: list-item;
  float: left;
  width: 100px; /* adjust depending on desired size */
}
```

To create the inline effect that you are looking for.

Comment: I attempted using the second method you suggested with the `<li>` tag and nothing changed in the layout, is there a setting for CSS that needs to be added?

Comment: I changed the example so that the form fields themselves are made to be list-items - removing the `<li>` wrappers, changing `li` reference in the css file to `input` and adding `display: list-item;`.  Without seeing your HTML/CSS, I think that should work.  Let me know! @Eatlon

Comment: They are still stacked like my example above. How can I get them in a line as: `Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday ....`

Comment: @Eatlon What HTML is being generated?

Comment: added the html generated

Comment: @Eatlon add `ul#dayForm label { display: list-item; float: left; width: 100px; }` to your css file.  Note the term `label` in your HTML and the new code.  Here's a good intro to inline lists which may help get you started with any additional styling that you need: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp  Another good discussion: http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/

Comment: Thanks for the input, still looks a little rough but its definitely better than the previous vertical styling. I will vote as correct